# GraphQL Unknown Field

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm totally stumped on why this is a problem.

Here is my data:

```
menuLinks: [
  {
    icon: 'home',
    label: 'Brochures and Reports',
    to: '/',
    subLinks: []
  },
  {
    icon: 'shield',
    label: 'Publications',
    to: '/',
    subLinks: []
  },  
  {
    icon: 'home',
    label: 'Published Essays and Public Testimony',
    to: '/',
    subLinks: []
  },
  {
    icon: 'shield',
    label: 'Curricular Resources',
    to: '/',
    subLinks: []
  },    
  {
    icon: 'shield',
    label: 'Transcripts',
    to: '/',
    subLinks: []
  }
]
```

Here is my query

```
query SiteTitleQuery {
                    site {
                      siteMetadata {
                        title
                        menuLinks {
                          icon,
                          label,
                          to,
                          subLinks {
                            icon,
                            label,
                            to
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
```

Here is my error

> ERROR #85907  GRAPHQL
>
> There was an error in your GraphQL query:
>
> - Unknown field 'subLinks' on type '[SiteSiteMetadataMenuLinks]'.

How is the field unknown?

Answer (score 0):

In `subLinks: []` you define an array.

In your graphQL query you define an object

```
subLinks {
  icon,
  label,
  to
}
```

An array is not an object. GraphQl expects an object key `subLinks` that contains object but finds `subLinks` that contains an array.

I think changing your sublinks in your data object to `subLinks: {}` (note the curly braces) should suffice.